# Using Socket.io to pass JavaScript Variables

Tags: javascript, python, ios, socket.io

so I currently have a JavaScript code that I run on my iPhone to pull its Accelerometer data. What I would like to do is Pass this data to my Mac Book Pro and use the variables in A python Script. The Variables are changing multiple times a second so I was thinking of using Socket.io, does anyone know how i would go about this? I would greatly appreciate any help I can get. Thank you.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <h1>Accelerometer JavaScript Test</h1>
<ul>
    <li>acceleration x: <span id="accelerationX"></span></li>
    <li>acceleration y: <span id="accelerationY"></span></li>
    <li>Motor Speed: <span id="speed"></span></li>
</ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.ondevicemotion = function(e){
        var x = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.x;
        var y = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.y;
        var newx = x * 100
        var newy = y * 100
        var finalx = Math.round(x);
        var finaly = Math.round(y);
        document.getElementById("accelerationX").innerHTML = finalx
        document.getElementById("accelerationY").innerHTML = finaly
        speed = finalx * 10
        document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = speed
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you just go and check out the docs?

Comment: Thanks for reading my post, I have spent countless hours searching for a specific tutorial on this but no luck, if you could point me in the direction of useful resources that would be great!

Comment: Are you trying to directly pass it to your macbook pro?

Comment: yes, just iPhone to Mac

Comment: Except you are sharing wifi or something.. This is not going to be a *simple* task.

Answer (score 1):

in client side you must use `socket.emit('key', value);`
and in server side you must listen for a key, for example in nodeJS its like this 
`socket.on('key', function(value){});`

Comment: sorry im brand new t socket.io, so how would i apply this to app?

Comment: heres a all example and documentation, you must to download a js file and use it. http://socket.io/

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I have already looked at that example, im just confused on how I would send the variable speed in my javascript using socket.io

Comment: socket.emit('speed', speed);

Comment: thank you, so client = socket.emit('speed', speed); then server = socket.on('speed', function(speed){});

Comment: I could not get it to work it responded with an error saying it did not recognize socket.on on the server side

Comment: have you installed socket.io on server ?

Answer (score 0):

wow you asked this in a lot of places...
I answered it here:

[Using Socket.io and iPhone Accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449596/using-socket-io-and-iphone-accelerometer/20452299#20452299)