# Using Socket.io and iPhone Accelerometer

Tags: javascript, ios

so I currently have a JavaScript code that I run on my iPhone to pull its Accelerometer data. What I would like to do is Pass this data to my Mac Book Pro. The Variables are changing multiple times a second so I was thinking of using Socket.io, does anyone know how i would go about this? I would greatly appreciate any help I can get. Thank you.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <h1>Accelerometer JavaScript Test</h1>
<ul>
    <li>acceleration x: <span id="accelerationX"></span></li>
    <li>acceleration y: <span id="accelerationY"></span></li>
    <li>Motor Speed: <span id="speed"></span></li>
</ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.ondevicemotion = function(e){
        var x = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.x;
        var y = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.y;
        var newx = x * 100
        var newy = y * 100
        var finalx = Math.round(x);
        var finaly = Math.round(y);
        document.getElementById("accelerationX").innerHTML = finalx
        document.getElementById("accelerationY").innerHTML = finaly
        speed = finalx * 10
        document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = speed
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either:

a) host a (websocket, probably node.js is easiest) server on your macbook pro, and connect to your computer's IP addr from your phone, but this would only work on your local network.

b) host a (websocket, probably node.js is easiest) server on a service like AWS EC2 or nodejitsu or something and connect to it from your phone and computer and then match up the sockets on the server side and pass data between them.

"a)" is simpler, and either way this should get you started (make sure include socket.io first, and initialize it properly, on both ends)

on the client:

```
// set up your socket

var socket = io.connect('http://' + location.host, {
     'reconnect': true,
     'reconnection delay': 50,
     'max reconnection attempts': 300
});

window.ondevicemotion = function(e){
    var x = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.x;
    var y = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.y;
    var z = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.z;

    // send data over the socket
    socket.emit('acceleration', {'x':x, 'y':y, 'z':z});
}
```

On your (node) server:

```
// set up server to listen on port 8888 - It will be accessible at YOUR.COMPS.IP.ADDR:8888 

var httpServ = http.createServer(app).listen(8888, function () {
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(httpServ, { log: true });

// wait for connection

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){

// if you receive data labeled 'acceleration' from this socket then print it out

    socket.on('acceleration', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this but I get the error "ReferenceError: http is not defined" when i start it, i think because createServer no longer works

Comment: it is because it is not defined. You should look at the node.js documentation... I didnt do ALL the work, you have to initialize your socket.io correctly. var http = require('http'); should initialize it correctly